# Calculating the Memory Usage of java Object with VisualVM Heap Dump does not match with theoretical approach

Tags: java, memory, jvm, jvm-hotspot

All I come with a simple question. According to the java docs and many articles about java memory object layout if we have a class with one `int` variable the total memory consumption for that object will be:

- 8 byte for the heading

  4 byte for the int

  4 byte padding (to round the total up to be multiple of 8 bytes) = **16** bytes total

```
public class Ab {        
    int b;
}
```

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    Ab ab = new AB();  
}
```

My problem now is that when I used the Visual vm and look at the Heap dump to observe this the theoretical approach I noticed that the memory consumption for that object was **20** byte instead of **16**? Why is this happens? Can someone explain to me?

Comment: Objects are always a multiple of 8 bytes (which is the reason for the padding as you mentioned) Note: on 64-bit JVMs, the header is 12 bytes by default, not that it makes a difference.

Comment: @ PeterLawrey  if the header is 12 bytes on 64-bit JVM then you have solved my problem i guess. i forgot to mention that the visual vm runs on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.161-b12, mixed mode). so it will be  12+4+4=20 bytes.Am i right?

Comment: @ Peter Lawrey if the header is 12 bytes + 4-byte int we have total 16 bytes we don't need to round up.How  20 explained?

Comment: [What Heap Dumps Are Lying To You About](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/heapdump-is-a-lie/)

Comment: VisualVM is wrong. The size of AB instrance should be 16 bytes: 12 bytes header + 4 bytes int field. [Eclipse MAT](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/) shows the correct size.

Comment: @apangin i don't think that VisualVm is wrong. There is an explanation for all.@Oleksandr below gave a nice approach for a solution. i am not an expert but it seems fair to me. What is your opinion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [Java Object Layout](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/) tool I received the following output:

```
 OFFSET  SIZE   TYPE DESCRIPTION        VALUE
      0    12        (object header)    N/A
     12     4    int Ab.b               N/A

Instance size: 16 bytes
Space losses: 0 bytes internal + 0 bytes external = 0 bytes total
```

And with the `-XX:-UseCompressedOops` VM option (disable compressed references):

```
 OFFSET  SIZE   TYPE DESCRIPTION                                VALUE
      0    16        (object header)                            N/A
     16     4    int Ab.b                                       N/A
     20     4        (loss due to the next object alignment)

Instance size: 24 bytes
Space losses: 0 bytes internal + 4 bytes external = 4 bytes total
```

Java environment:

```
java version "11" 2018-09-25
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11+28)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11+28, mixed mode)
```

Comment: i want to upvote but i can't. i think you have the perfect answer. UseCompressedOops is the key

Comment: BTW Compressed Oops is off if your heap is larger than 32 GB. +1

Comment: @MixalisNavridis The actual size is 24 bytes used with padding in this case.

Answer (score 1):

According to "Object header layout" section in hotspot documentation:
https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/CompressedOops

"An object header consists of a native-sized mark word, a klass word, a 32-bit length word (if the object is an array), a 32-bit gap (if required by alignment rules), and then zero or more instance fields, array elements, or metadata fields.

So it would mean that in your case it looks like this:

- 8 byte for mark word (8 byte on 64 bit architectures)
- 4 byte for klass word (because by default compressed oops are used)
- 8 byte gap (that is where your int field is stored)